# Nearby Friends looking at your location

Tags: facebook

When "seeing your precise location" pops up on Facebook Nearby Friends, does it mean that person you are sharing with is looking at it right at that moment? Can you tell when they look at your location?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its when you authorize Facebook to log your precise location then everyone sees your precise location